# Setting Extension Filter in FileChooser in javafx without description

Tags: javafx, file-extension, filechooser

I know a way of adding a file extension in FileChooser in javafx:

```
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();

chooser.getExtensionFilters().add("JPG Files(*.JPG)", "*.jpg");
```

But is there any way I can do this without any `description` argument and just care about the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, as there is no such constructor for [`ExtensionFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.ExtensionFilter.html). There are two constructors and both need a `description`.

You need to pass a string in place of description, though you can pass an empty string `""` ;)